# How to ‘invert’ or ‘reverse’ a vector cutline when gdalwarp'ing a raster?

Tags: raster, gdal, vector, gdalwarp, masking

I have a raster of North America and I'd like to *remove* the larger lakes from it, replacing them with the same no-data value as the original raster.

So I downloaded Natural Earth's [10 meter lakes](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-lakes/) vector data, which has lakes conveniently ranked by scale rank: 0 for large lakes like the Great Lakes, and larger scale ranks for more minor lakes.

The closest I've come with `gdalwarp` is:

```
$ gdalwarp -cutline Data/ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp \
  -csql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_lakes WHERE scalerank=0" \
  INPUT.tif lakes-only.tif
```

This actually does the *opposite* of what I want, it *keeps* only the Great Lakes portions of my raster, replacing all other non-lake pixels with the no-data value.

My question: how can I **invert** the cutline, so instead of getting the area inside the lake boundary, I get whatever is outside it? Can I invert the original Natural Earth .shp file, perhaps?

**References**

In [How to invert polygons (or other options for exterior styling)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55059/how-to-invert-polygons-or-other-options-for-exterior-styling), GRASS' [`r.mask`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mask.html) was suggested, which has an inverse mode. Is there something similar with OGR/GDAL?

In [How to get an ocean shapefile from a very detailed land area shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21885/how-to-get-an-ocean-shapefile-from-a-very-detailed-land-area-shapefile), the .shp file was converted to a raster, then inverted, and used as a mask. I'd prefer not to generate a raster of non-lakes because my original TIFF raster is very large (high resolution) and I'd prefer not to generate a raster of the same size. As a stopgap though, I was able to do this:

```
# Create a not-lakes raster of the same spacing and extent as INPUT
$ gdal_rasterize -i -burn 255 -a_nodata 0 -ot Byte \
  -te `gdalinfo INPUT.tif | egrep "Lower Left|Upper Right"|cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1 | sed 's/,//'| tr "\n" " "` \
  -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_lakes WHERE scalerank=0" \
  -tr `gdalinfo INPUT.tif |grep "Pixel Size"|cut -d"(" -f2|sed 's/[,)]/ /g'` \
  Data/ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp lakes.tif
# Apply the lakes raster to input as some kind of mask
$ gdal_calc.py -A INPUT.tif -B lakes.tif --outfile OUTPUT.tif --calc='A' \
  --NoDataValue=0
```

Can something similar be done without creating a gigantic non-lake raster?

Comment: You can use gdal_rasterize and burn lake polygons into the image with fixed color.

Comment: That would be really neat, using gdal_rasterize to modify the raster without the creation of a secondary lakes-related raster. But the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) doesn't seem to specify any way to manipulate a raster in this way with gdal_rasterize? It seems to accept one data source and one destination file?

Comment: @user30184 got it! I thought the "destination filename" was strictly for outputs, but I just tried to give it the input file and what you said worked perfectly! Can you post an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @user30184 Write this in an answer: “gdal_rasterize can burn a fixed color for polygons into an existing raster: `gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_lakes WHERE scalerank=0" Data/ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp INPUT.tif`” so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdal_rasterize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html can burn a fixed color for polygons into an existing raster:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_lakes WHERE scalerank=0" Data/ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp DESTINATION.tif
```

According to the documentation the output raster must support update mode access. Which formats support update mode can be checked with gdalinfo by looking at + sign in the driver capabilities. However, updating compressed images may fail or it can lead to sub-optimal result. Uncompressed TIFF is the safest choice but in theory other formats from this list should work as well.

```
gdalinfo --formats | find "+"

FITS -raster- (rw+): Flexible Image Transport System
HDF4Image -raster- (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
KEA -raster- (rw+): KEA Image Format (.kea)
netCDF -raster- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format
VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
PCRaster -raster- (rw+): PCRaster Raster File
ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
SGI -raster- (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
Leveller -raster- (rw+): Leveller heightfield
Terragen -raster- (rw+): Terragen heightfield
ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
PAux -raster- (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
MFF -raster- (rw+v): Vexcel MFF Raster
MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
ROI_PAC -raster- (rw+v): ROI_PAC raster
ISCE -raster- (rw+v): ISCE raster
ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
```