# Changing raster pixel values outside of polygon box using rioxarray

Tags: raster, polygon, pixel, rioxarray, values

How do I change all raster pixel values outside of a polygon (keep the original values inside polygon) into a certain value?

I have passed through rioxarray clip() like below from this [link](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html):

```
geometries = [
    {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[
            [425499.18381405267, 4615331.540546387],
            [425499.18381405267, 4615478.540546387],
            [425526.18381405267, 4615478.540546387],
            [425526.18381405267, 4615331.540546387],
            [425499.18381405267, 4615331.540546387]
        ]]
    }
]
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geometries)
```

What I am looking for is something similar to this, but instead of clipping it will change the values outside of that polygon.

Something like:

```
change_values_outside_polygon(geometries, changed_value=-999)
```

Comment: You can do that with https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html. Also Pythonized version exists in the GDAL Python bindings.

Comment: Hi @user30184, thank you for your answer. Could you please give a bit more information about that? As I read here https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html it is about converting other types of file into raster. There is no information about how to use gdal_rasterize() to change the raster pixel values outside a polygon. So sorry, I am not familiar much with this area.

Comment: The documantation is a bit unclear but you can update an existing raster. See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173308/how-to-invert-or-reverse-a-vector-cutline-when-gdalwarping-a-raster. So you take an existing raster and a polygon  and tell gdal_rasterize to "burn" new pixel values, and with `-i` option that the outside of the polygon gets updated.

Comment: I voted to re-open this as a rioxarray question. If you wish to ask about doing this using GDAL then please do that in a separate question.